# Best practice on observing value changes in UITableView's cells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, key-value-observing

Suppose I have a `UITableView` with `UITextField` cells, corresponding to a model object's properties. And suppose I want to KVO the cells in order to sync the model accordingly
(as w/could be done via bindings on OS X).

What's the proper (vanilla) way to do this?
<sup>(I'm talking about the `view`->`controller`->`model` direction. Other direction is clear to me.)</sup>

Currently I'm setting my view controller as the fields' `delegate` and assign it a unique (`enum`'d) **tag** in:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

and then implement:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSUInteger tag = textField.tag;
    switch (tag) {
        case SomeTextFieldTag: {
            self.foo = textField.text;
            break;
        }
        case SomeOtherTextFieldTag: {
            self.bar = textField.text;
            break;
        }
        ...
        default: {
            break;
        }
    }   
}
```

But this just doesn't scale well (in regards to dev effort/maintenance) and feels clumsy/fishy.
In particular as I'm abusing the tags for what feels like they're simply not intended for (as the book-keeping of associating textfields with model property keys should be done on the controller's part, not via tags on the MVC's view layer or via any [other means](http://inessential.com/2012/12/31/uitableviewcell_is_not_a_controller)).

So I figured I could instead do **proper KVO observing** on the fields and use a **different KVO context** for each field, instead of a tag. But this feels just a little less fishy (book-keeping-wise), yet just as clumsy as did before. Like I'm just moving maintenance problems around. (Also while tags could be assigned dynamically, doing so with contexts feels somewhat wrong to me.)

Coming from OS X and being used to bindings in collection views I was rather surprised to not find any supposedly reliable resources on this matter.
Or maybe I'm just to dump to search properly? Any official programming guides on this particular topic, that I missed the memo on?

What's a/the widely accepted **best practice** for this supposedly oh-so common scenario?

---

Proper native block-based KVO observing would make this so much simpler. No book-keeping required at all:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = ...;
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case ...: {
            [cell addObserverForKeyPath:@"..." inContext:classContext withBlock:^(id object, NSString *keyPath, NSDictionary *change) {
                self.model.foo = changes[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
            }];
            ...
            break;
        }
        ...
        default: {
            break;
        }
    }
    ...
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [cell removeObserverForKeyPath:nil inContext:classContext];
}
```